# What's better in designing object attachment in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I need to represent adding attachments to order or order item using sql server.
I think of two ways but wonder which one is better.

Solution 1:

```
table1: attachment (id, name, description, uri, ...)
table2: order (id, client_id, ...)
table3: orderItem (id, order_id, product_id, ...)
table2: objectAttachment (id, objectType, object_id, attachment_id, ...)
```

In this case I retrieved order attachments like this:

```
create proc GetOrderAttachments(@order_id int)
AS
select attachment_name, attachment_uri, attachment_desription, order.(...)
from objectAttachment orderAttachment
inner join order on order.id = orderAttachment.object_id
inner join attachment on attachment.id = orderAttachment.attachment_id 
where orderAttachment.objectType = 'order' and orderAttachment.object_id = @order_id
```

Solution 2:

```
table1: attachment (id, name, description, uri, ...)
table2: orderAttachment (id, order_id, orderItem_id, ...)
table3: order (id, client_id, ...)
table4: orderItem (id, order_id, product_id, ...)
```

In this case I retrieved order attachments like this (knowing that `orderItem_id` is neglected):

```
create proc GetOrderAttachments(@order_id int)
AS
select attachment_name, attachment_uri, attachment_desription, order.(...)
from orderAttachment orderAttachment
inner join order on order.id = orderAttachment.order_id
inner join attachment on attachment.id = orderAttachment.attachment_id  and orderAttachment.order_id = @order_id
```

Comment: I'm trying to decide between a Mercedes and a Subaru. Which one is better?

Comment: @AaronBertrand you cant tell which is better but you can tell about positives and negatives of both.

Comment: @Giorgi and how do you come up with a "right" answer when it is just a list of pros and cons? These "which is better" types of questions are not a very good fit here.

Answer (score 0):

Lets consider various situations and compare each approach.

**Question. How many attachment are there of any type?**

1 approach will select from one table(good).

2 approach will need to union many tables.

What if you add one more entity with attachments. You will need to remember all places where you are answering questions like this and add one more case. First approach is safe from this point of view.

**You are asked to add additional attributes for order attachments and some other attributes for some other entity's attachments.**

With first approach you will need to add attributes of both in one table which will be nullable and filled for just one type of entity type.

Second approach is safe. You add attributes to appropriate entities. There are no many many nullable columns just to maintain one type of attachment.

**You are asked to delete all attachments of orders.**

With first approach if you have huge amount of data delete operation will take long period of time.

With second approach you can remove relationships and truncate table which will take millisecond.

---

You can continue this list. Answering various questions and considering cons and pros of different approaches will help you to decide which approach fits better to your needs. There wouldn't be just one correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no better solution. All depends on your needs. The problem here is which table inheritance model fits for you.

You can start reading here:

Single Table Inheritance
Class Table Inheritance
Concrete Table Inheritance

[Single Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html)

[Class Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html)

*ttp://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/concreteTableInheritance.html